# Is this sentence gramatically true ? " Is that spelt the same as the colour"

Tags: grammar

I was practicing English that i came a cross the  sentence " Is that spelt the same as the color" but this sentence looks like a bit odd to me so i wonder what grammar topic should i learn to understand the structure of this type of sentences ?

Comment: Spelt and colour are British spellings; spelled and color are American. You should be consistent.

Comment: ...and better to use "spelled" because to North Americans, "spelt" is a grain.

Comment: What about that sentence strikes you as odd?

Comment: @gotube sorry for late response. i though the question form should have been something like Do\Does + ... but i think now its question form of a passive sentence (right?) so it make more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence looks odd to me, but only because *spelt* is AFAIK not used in American English (the alternative *spelled* is used in all varieties, but *spelt* is used in British and perhaps other Commonwealth varieties), but *color* is used in American English and not British.

But grammatically it's fine: I interpret it as (in my British English) *Is that spelt the same way as the colour which sounds like it?* for example *blue* as opposed to *blew*.

Answer (score 0):

English usually indicates a *query* or *interrogative sentence* by reversing the standard subject-verb order. This is a statement:

> That is spelt the same as the color.

This is a question:

> Is that spelt the same as the color?

("That" is a pronoun referring to some previously mentioned thing, perhaps a person's last name.)

Besides reversing the subject and verb, we also indicate a question by ending the sentence with a *question mark* `?` when writing it down, and by inflecting our speech upward at the end when saying it out loud.

You will find more information by looking up "question structure in English" or similar search terms.